# Describe sets in Euclidean Space

Tags: real-analysis

Describe the sets $B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \operatorname{norm}(x) \leq 3\}$ and $Q = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \operatorname{norm}(x) < 3\}$.

I think set B means $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and all the length of the elements $x$ are less than or equal to 3.

And $Q$ means $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and all the length of the elements $x$ is less than 3.

Wondering am I correct.

Comment: Hint: think about how this would work in the plane.

Comment: A pair of balls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \operatorname{norm}(x) \leq 3\}=$$

$$  \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 9\} $$

That is a closed  ball centered at the origin with radius $3$

$$Q = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \operatorname{norm}(x) < 3\}=$$
$$  \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2 <9\} $$

That is an open  ball centered at the origin with radius $3$